# How to run downstream dynamic tasks as soon as dependencies are fullfilled?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I have an airflow DAG using 3 Tasks.
Task 1 is generating a map, based on which I'm branching out downstream tasks.

The pipeline loooks like this:

```
Task 1 --> Task 2a --> Task 3a
     |
     |---> Task 2b --> Task 3b
```

My problem: If I have a failure in 2a but 2b is successful, I want 3b to run. Right now, it seems that Task 3 isn't running at all.

How can I do that?

I was expecting downstream tasks to run as soon as dependencies are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

The default trigger_rule is "all_success", if you want to run Task3 to run after Task2 no matter its state, you can change Task3 trigger_rule to "all_done".

for more details you can see this [article](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-trigger-rules-all-you-need-to-know/)